# How to create a relationship if a contact marked with multiple subtype?

Tags: relationships

I have 3 contact subtypes.

1. Contributing member
2. Volunteers
3. Patron

some of members have multiple subtypes associated to their record. When I try to create a relationship of a **"Patron"** with a contact marked **"Contributing member & Volunteer"** it does not work, if relationship **A-B** are set to the contact subtypes. It only works if selected relationship **A-B** are both ***Individuals*** and not the **subtypes**. Anyway to fix it, so that I can use the contacts that uses multiple contacts subtypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spotted the problem. It was working all the way through. But the auto search was not showing the result. It would only show the result below when I click search button. It happens if either of the contact marked with multiple subtypes. Now, I have removed other subtypes and kept only the ones related to relationship for both contact. And now it shows the auto search results.. as I am using 4.4.16, I tried with 4.4 demo site and i can reproduce this. [image]

Comment: If you can reproduce this and think it is a bug you could add it to the issue tracker on http://issues.civicrm.org/ (if it is not there already)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand, I have a relationship on my install between subtype 'Suplier' and subtype 'recruiter'? Can you explain what is different?
[image]

Comment: Only difference I can see in your example is the contact type. My both contact type is Individual subtype vs individual subtype. Whereas yours is organisation-individual.

Comment: That might explain, I will try to create an individual - individual :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have now also added a relationship between two subtypes of Individual? Can you reproduce your situation on the CiviCRM demo site?
[image]

Comment: I just spotted the problem. It was working all the way through. But the auto search was not showing the result. It would only show the result below when I click search button. It happens if either of the contact marked with multiple subtypes. Now, I have removed other subtypes and kept only the ones related to relationship for both contact. And now it shows the auto search results.. as I am using 4.4.16, I tried with 4.4 demo site and i can reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism for creating relationships has changed considerably between 4.4 and the current stable release (4.6). The core team is not fixing issues in 4.4 and I suspect the LTS team will not consider this issues either as they generally limit 4.4 changes to security and data loss problems.